# How to make one binded key execute two commands in tkinter, python?

Tags: python, tkinter

So what I'm trying to do is to make my tkinter window close after pressing enter key but at the same time execute the given command with enter

```
newWindow.bind("<Return>", ui_add)
newWindow.bind("<Return>", newWindow.destroy)
```

I want Return key to execute function ui_add and AFTER that make the window close.
It just closes the window and the first command is not executed.

Comment: how about You add `newWindow.destroy()` at the end of `ui_add` function?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, make a new function that does both of those things.

Comment: Well it's not that easy, this window is created inside another function, since it is not the master window, but thanks anyway

Comment: Have you tried `newWindow.bind("<Return>", lambda e: ui_add())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create a new function. There are other ways, but this is the simplest to debug and maintain.

```
def callback(event):
    ui_add(event)
    new_window.destroy()

newWindow.bind(‘<Return>’, callback)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm mad at myself knowing how easy it was